# `key_press_event` not working in python matplotlib FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, events, matplotlib

I can't get a `FuncAnimation` to end gracefully. I am running in a mac OS X environment with anaconda 2.7 python. At the end of the animation, the program just hangs, even with a ^C. I have to close the matplotlib window.

So, I decided to try catching a key press, but the same thing happens even with the matplotlib example below.

Two questions: 1) How can I end `FuncAnimation` gracefully, and 2) How can I get the key_press_event to work? I have included the matplotlib example that also hangs.

```
"""
Show how to connect to keypress events
"""
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def press(event):
    print('press', event.key)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if event.key == 'x':
        visible = xl.get_visible()
        xl.set_visible(not visible)
        fig.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)

ax.plot(np.random.rand(12), np.random.rand(12), 'go')
xl = ax.set_xlabel('easy come, easy go')
ax.set_title('Press a key')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The example runs fine as it is. There is no clue is given as to what could cause this the figure window to hang. But you would rather want to try and solve that problem instead of working around it.

Comment: Try changing the backend (e.g., to `TKAgg`) and see if you have the same problems then. There seem to be a lot of problems of this kind with the default `MacOSX` backend.